# How to align three text expressions evenly and centered in one line vertically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a single page HTML which I want its header contents in mobile/tablet to be like in the photo attached . I have tried several ways but no luck :

Here is the desired result :

[image]

And Here is the Code I've Used :

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
            background-color: black;
        }
        
        .title {
            text-align: center;
            background-color : white;
            color : black;
            height: 100px;
            padding: 35px 0;
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: 1;
            position: fixed;
            font-family: Clearface, sans-serif;
            font-size: 40px;
        }

        .header #accordion-0 {
            font-size: 25px;
        }

        #about {
            background-color: black;
            color : white;
            float : left;
            width : 50%;
            height : 100vh;
            font-family: Clearface, sans-serif;
            margin-top: 170px;
            position: fixed;
        }

        #about h2 {
            font-size: 80px;
            padding: 30px 70px 0 70px;
        }
        
        #about p {
            font-size: 30px;
            padding : 70px;
            padding-top: 0;
        }

        #projects .accordion {
            background-color: #333648;
            color: white;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 20px;
            width: 100%;
            border: none;
            text-align: center;
            outline: none;
            font-size: 17px;
            transition: 0.5s;
            height: 20%;
            font-family: 'Univers LT Std', sans-serif;
            font-size: 20px;
            opacity: 0.7;
        }

        #projects .active, #projects .accordion:hover {
            background-color: #ccc;
            color: black;
            opacity: 1;
        }

        .panel {
            padding:0 18px;
            background-color: white;
            max-height: 0;
            overflow-y: hidden;
            transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out;

        }

        .post {
            padding: 0 20%;
            font-family: 'Univers LT Std', sans-serif;
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        .img-responsive {
            display: block;
            max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            margin: 50px auto;
        }

        #projects {
            float : right;
            width: 50%;
            height: 100vh;
            font-family: 'Univers LT Std', sans-serif;
            font-size : 20px;
            margin-top: 170px;
        }

        #about-accordion h2, #about-accordion p{
            font-family: Clearface, sans-serif;
        }

        #about-accordion .panel{
            background-color: black;
            color : white;
        }
        
        #about-accordion {
            font-size: 30px;
        }

        /* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
        @media only screen 
        and (min-device-width : 320px) 
        and (max-device-width : 480px) {
            #about {
                display : none;
            }

            #projects {
                width: 100%;
            }

        }
        
        /* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
        @media only screen 
        and (min-device-width : 768px) 
        and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
            #about {
                display : none;
            }

            #projects {
                width: 100%;
            }
            
        }

        /* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
        @media only screen 
        and (min-width : 1224px) {
            #about-accordion {
                display : none;
            }

            .header #accordion-0 {
                display : none;
            }

            #dash {
                display : none;
            }
        }

        /* Large screens ----------- */
        @media only screen 
        and (min-width : 1824px) {
            #about-accordion {
                display : none;
            }

            .header #accordion-0 {
                display : none;
            }

            #dash {
                display : none;
            }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>


<h1 class="header title">
    <span id="hello-back"> Hello <br> Back </span>
    <span id="dash"> - </span>
    <span id="accordion-0" class="accordion">About Me</span>
</h1>

<div id="about">
    <h2>
        Hello!
    </h2>

    <p> 
        Lorem Ipsum är en utfyllnadstext från tryck- och förlagsindustrin. Lorem ipsum har varit standard ända sedan 1500-talet, när en okänd boksättare tog att antal bokstäver och blandade dem för att göra ett provexemplar av en bok. Lorem ipsum har inte bara överlevt fem århundraden, utan även övergången till elektronisk typografi utan större förändringar. Det blev allmänt känt på 1960-talet i samband med lanseringen av Letraset-ark med avsnitt av Lorem Ipsum, och senare med mjukvaror som Aldus PageMaker.
    </p>
</div>

<div id="projects">
    <div id="about-accordion">
        <div id="panel-0" class="panel">
            <div class="post">
                <h2>
                    Hello!
                </h2>
            
                <p> 
                    Lorem Ipsum är en utfyllnadstext från tryck- och förlagsindustrin. Lorem ipsum har varit standard ända sedan 1500-talet, när en okänd boksättare tog att antal bokstäver och blandade dem för att göra ett provexemplar av en bok. Lorem ipsum har inte bara överlevt fem århundraden, utan även övergången till elektronisk typografi utan större förändringar. Det blev allmänt känt på 1960-talet i samband med lanseringen av Letraset-ark med avsnitt av Lorem Ipsum, och senare med mjukvaror som Aldus PageMaker.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="accordion-1" class="accordion">Project 1</button>
    <div id="panel-1" class="panel">
        <div class="post">
            <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
            <p>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
            <div>
                <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button id="accordion-2" class="accordion">Project 2</button>
    <div id="panel-2" class="panel">
        <div class="post">
            <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
            <p>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.


            </p>
            <div>
                <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button  id="accordion-3" class="accordion">Project 3</button>
    <div id="panel-3" class="panel">
        <div class="post">
            <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
            <p>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.


            </p>
            <div>
                <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button id="accordion-4" class="accordion">Project 4</button>
    <div id="panel-4" class="panel">
        <div class="post">
            <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
            <p>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.


            </p>
            <div>
                <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button id="accordion-5" class="accordion">Project 5</button>
    <div id="panel-5" class="panel">
        <div class="post">
            <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
            <p>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.


            </p>
            <div>
                <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var accordion = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < accordion.length; i++) {
        accordion[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            var patt = /(accordion-)(\d)/gm;
            var match = patt.exec(this.id);
   panel = document.getElementById("panel-" + match[2]);

            if (panel.style.maxHeight){
                panel.style.maxHeight = null;
            } else {
                panels = document.getElementsByClassName('panel');
    for(j = 0; j < panels.length; j++) {
     if(panels[j].id != panel.id) {
      panels[j].style.maxHeight = null;
      panels[j].classList.remove('active');
     }
    }
                panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
            }
   
   this.classList.toggle("active");
        });
    }

    function hscrollbar() {
        /* First, we need the horizontal scroll position of the viewer's display,
        but there are different ways to call it in JS depending on browser.
        I'm using the if/else shorthand notation to detect if a call is legit: 
        somevar = (statement) ? statement_true_value : statement_false_value */
        var left = 
            /* window.pageXOffset should work for most recent browsers: */
            window.pageXOffset ? window.pageXOffset : 
            /* If it DOESN'T, let's try this: */
            document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : 
            /* And if THAT didn't work: */
            document.body.scrollLeft;

        /* Now that we have the horizontal scroll position, set #footpanel's left 
        position to NEGATIVE the value, so it APPEARS to follow the scroll: */
        document.getElementById('about').style.left = -left;
    }
    window.onscroll = hscrollbar; /* Call the function when the user scrolls */
    window.onresize = hscrollbar; /* Call the function when the window resizes */
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flex-box`, add to your `.title` class the following:

```
.title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: is there any way to do it in CSS 2.0 ?

Comment: You can `float` the elements, and apply to them the same `width` and apply a `line-height` to get them aligned vertically